# Correct way to get mean, describe values from large data set in pandas

Tags: pandas, hdfstore

I am getting "array is too big" for hdf_read, which may mean I have to iterate through the file and compute results in chunks before combining them together; I was wondering if there is an automated way of doing this? Or perhaps a better way that I am unaware of?

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Right now I use the following to load the file:

```
res= pd.read_hdf(self.file, self.key, columns = get_columns)
```

Followed by the following to compute the mean:

```
describe = res.describe()
text=''
count = int(describe['count'])
text+= 'Count: %s\n' % (str(count))
text+= 'Mean: %s\n' % (str(describe['mean']))
text+= 'Standard Deviation: %s\n' % (str(describe['std']))
text+= 'Range: [%s, %s]\n' % (str(int(describe['min'])), str(int(describe['max'])))
text+= "25%%: %s\n" % (str(int(describe['25%'])))
text+= "50%% (median): %s\n" % (str(int(describe['50%'])))
text+= "75%%: %s\n" % (str(int(describe['75%'])))
text+= "Unbiased Kurtosis: %s\n" % (str(res.kurt()))
text+= "Unbiased Skew: %s\n" % (str(res.skew()))
text+= "Unbiased Variance: %s\n" % (str(res.var()))
```

Running this on the HDF file (812MB in blosc), yields

```
res= pd.read_hdf(self.file, self.key, columns = get_columns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 330, in read_hdf
    return f(store, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 322, in <lambda>
    key, auto_close=auto_close, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 669, in select
    auto_close=auto_close).get_values()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1335, in get_values
    results = self.func(self.start, self.stop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 658, in func
    columns=columns, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3822, in read
    if not self.read_axes(where=where, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3056, in read_axes
    values = self.selection.select()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 4339, in select
    return self.table.table.read(start=self.start, stop=self.stop)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/table.py", line 1975, in read
    arr = self._read(start, stop, step, field, out)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/table.py", line 1865, in _read
    result = self._get_container(nrows)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/table.py", line 958, in _get_container
    return numpy.empty(shape=shape, dtype=self._v_dtype)
ValueError: array is too big.
```

pd.show_versions():

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.6.final.0
python-bits: 32
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.13.0-24-generic
machine: i686
processor: i686
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.14.1
nose: 1.3.1
Cython: 0.20.1post0
numpy: 1.8.1
scipy: 0.13.3
statsmodels: 0.5.0
IPython: 1.2.1
sphinx: 1.2.2
patsy: 0.2.1
scikits.timeseries: None
dateutil: 1.5
pytz: 2012c
bottleneck: 0.8.0
tables: 3.1.1
numexpr: 2.2.2
matplotlib: 1.3.1
openpyxl: None
xlrd: None
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: 3.3.3
bs4: 4.2.1
html5lib: 0.999
httplib2: 0.8
apiclient: None
rpy2: None
sqlalchemy: 0.8.4
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
```

ptdump:
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0pxtdm0ccekgoj/ptdump.txt?dl=0)

Comment: post some code that you use to read and ptdump -av would make the context more informative

Comment: I posted some code, the data is large (812MB), and loading yields the posted error.

Comment: you need to show ptdump -av <file> and pd.shoe_versions()

Comment: Posted. Thanks for all the support!

Comment: seems like you passed data_columns=True ? not a good idea; are you really planning in querying on potentially every column? I think their is to much meta data - just list the columns that you are likely to query on (it will also make this quite a bit faster). you still may need to read in chunks as you do have a bit of data - you might be running out of memory; see the section on iteration

Comment: just noticed u r 32-bit. this will severely limit what you can do as you will be only able to allocate a small amount of memory. you will for sure need to read in chunks and if you really want to work use 64-bit python (not so easy on 32-bit Linux but nevertheless)

Comment: I do use iteration in other cases; but that would mean I will not be able to easily compute such things as mean, not a big deal, just a bit more work (adding together means of chunks, figuring out how kurtosis can be derived from different chunks, etc.). I actually do need every column =/ What do you mean by data_columns=True not being a good idea? How is that evident? The one relevant to the mean is age... but then I may need to connect age to everything else.

Comment: Or what do you mean by listing only the fields that are relevant? Are you saying it would be better to divide up the files each to its own field? (And then have to do some sort of join between files?)

Comment: you will get every column (unless you specify columns= on searching); data_columns have to do with which columns you query on explicitly see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#query-via-data-columns; it depends what kinds of queries you are doing.

Comment: furthermore you are probably better off splitting into multiple tables. read the docs; many examples of this. hdf5 is not a regular database and should be used for a smaller number of columns where you need very fast queries on lots of data. however you generally don't want very wide data; better to break it up.

Comment: It sounds like you might be saying that for this scenario, a RDBS would probably be better/more compact.

Comment: not at all. I suggest you simply use 64-bit which can easily handle this data. Its not even very big, just bigger that you can address in memory (in a trivial way)